# Reading resources using Value("classpath:asterisks") explaination

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Java, I know I can read resources using

```
@Value("classpath:file.json")
private Resource file // reads file.json
```

I've also seen people use

```
@Value("classpath:*.json")
private Resource[] files 
// reads file.json, file2.json, file3.json and file4.json, like a glob
```

but I don't understand the glob used, can I just use one asterisk, can I do more? I tried `**/**/*.json` but this didn't work.

I've tried searching but my searches have been unhelpful.

Comment: This [resource](https://stackabuse.com/the-value-annotation-in-spring/) will be more than enough, there are plenty of examples. Check [SpeL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Comment: it does give many examples of @value, however i want to know more about the glob i can use for classpaths. and this resource has no examples of classpath?

Comment: hey aris, i checked spel, but it also doesn't mention anything about the classpath. I am not evaluating anything afaik, since i don't start my value with "#"?

Comment: Yeap you are right, I didn't notice the `*`. For a strange reason, I cannot find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Globbing is useful to get multiple files, however the globbing is different to normal.
Notice the single asterisk rather than multiple.

```
@Value("classpath:docs/*/*.json")
private Resource[] files 
// reads docs/foo/file.json, docs/bar/file2.json etc.
```

Comment: not accepting, because the question posted was about getting some documentation or better insight into the asterisks, but this is still slightly helpful